# What is an example of user documentation?

Tags: c++, documentation

I'm writing this Rational number class for one of my cs courses, using C++. We're also asked to hand in a "user documentation", which is sth that i've never done before. What is an example of user documentation? what is the format of it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to give a document in .html? or are they asking only to comment the source code?

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a school assignment. Considering the level of complexity of your project, i don't think it's anything formal. Just comment your code and briefly explain how to use your class.

Answer (score 2):

"User Documentation" is written instructions you would give to someone using your software. In other words, write something that tells your end user, in this case your instructor, how to run your program.

Take a look at doxygen for a way to turn your code's comments into html user documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try Doxygen. It will dynamically generate some of the documentation.
For an examle, look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your instructor to clarify what he/she is asking for - that is what a good engineer would do...make sure to nail down the problem with the customer :)

User docs could mean:

- Source code docs (user is another program)
- README.txt file
- End-user doc in HTML, CHM, whatever

Answer (score 0):

Take it simple... use this snippet before methods replacing wherever necessary:

```
//**************************************************************
// Output condition over the program after method execution
// Input variables, their type and meanings
// Return value
//**************************************************************
```

You should see [Java API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) to notice how a documentation should be...